# React Native Ios Video install npm

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-video, video-component

I keep getting error when attempting to install Video component. I am typing in: `npm install --save react-native-video

```
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

did anyone else run into the problem? Above are the errors. says npm not being able to find file path? Confused because i am install the video component in the same folder i did the npm install package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install it with no issues, what was the stack trace you received when you tried to install the library?

I would run `npm config ls` and make sure you are pointing to the correct registry. Also, are you behind a proxy?

Maybe you could try the following and seeing if it helps resolve your issue:

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
3. `npm i react-native-video`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks. It is pointing to the correct registry. The npm i react-native-video cmd installed the package. but now im getting and error when adding the <Video /> component. the error says:  TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'u.NativeModeules.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants'

Comment: Did you import the newly download library? Something like: import Video from 'react-native-video'; Usually, undefined is because the object wasn't properly instantiated. Try following the usage example listed for the lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video